# Jaxb Unmarshalling (different wrapper elements with same element)

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I have below xml structure:

```
<Response>
<Field1>
    <User>
        <Name>abc</Name>
        <Id>1</Id>  
    </User>
</Field1>   
<Field2>
    <User>
        <Name>sdf</Name>
        <Id>2</Id>  
    </User>
</Field2>   
<Field3>
    <User>
        <Name>xyz</Name>
        <Id>3</Id>  
    </User>
</Field3>
...
</Response>
```

There are different Field(X) wrapper elements which contain the same User element.  There can be n number of Fields sent in the XML. Due to this I cannot have the separate Jaxb's for each. I need to get access to the User ignoring the Field elements after the unmarshalling step. Unfortunately I dont have access to change the xml structure. I am unable to find a solution for it. Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this on you `Response (root)` class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Response")
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {
    @XmlElements(value = {
            @XmlElement(name = "Field1", type = Field.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "Field2", type = Field.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "Field3", type = Field.class)
    })
    private Field field;
}
```

JAXB would automatically map to field class whenever it encounters the different `FIelds`.

**EDITED/UPDATED**

XML:

```
<Response>
    <Field1>
        <Name>abc</Name>
        <Id>1</Id>
    </Field1>
    <Field2>
        <Name>sdf</Name>
        <Id>2</Id>
    </Field2>
    <Field3>
        <Name>xyz</Name>
        <Id>3</Id>
    </Field3>
</Response>
```

Root:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Response")
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {
    @XmlAnyElement
    private List<Field> action;
}
```

Field:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Field {
    private String Name;
    private String Id;
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        final InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class).createUnmarshaller();
        final Root root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, Root.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(root.toString());

        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Root(action=[[Field1: null], [Field2: null], [Field3: null]])
<Response>
   <Field1>
      <Name>abc</Name>
      <Id>1</Id>
   </Field1>
   <Field2>
      <Name>sdf</Name>
      <Id>2</Id>
   </Field2>
   <Field3>
      <Name>xyz</Name>
      <Id>3</Id>
   </Field3>
</Response>
```